# PostgreSQL old master reports timeline diverge on rejoining to new master as a replica even though remote_apply synchronous replication is used

Tags: postgresql, failover, consistency

I am testing different scenarios of failover in PostgreSQL and I'm currently working on PostgreSQL 10.

Here is the cluster topology:

pg1: master

pg2: sync standby (streaming replication)

pg1 is configured to have all the transactions in sync with pg2 (`commit method` is `'remote_apply'` and `synchronous_standby_names` is `'pg2'`; `pg2` here is the `application_name` pg2 uses when replicating from pg1)

The scenario happens when the master is receiving lots of writes and is killed by force (`kill -9`). Then failover happens and pg2 gets promoted and becomes the new master. After that I try to bring pg1 back to the cluster as a standby and when trying to start replication, it reports the following error:

```
2019-12-29 21:39:05.404 +0330 [11] FATAL:  requested timeline 3 is not a child of this server's history
2019-12-29 21:39:05.404 +0330 [11] DETAIL:  Latest checkpoint is at 0/4C000028 on timeline 2, but in the history of the requested timeline, the server forked off from that timeline at 0/4BBAD980.
```

BTW, the reason that it is talking about timeline 2 & 3 is that this cluster has experienced another failover before.

This error can be fixed by using `pg_rewind` and it works, but what it does is to find the divergence of the timelines and then ignore whatever is remained and then follow the current master. And this encounters some kind of inconsistency and potentially data loss; which is obviously unexpected according to the configurations (which is remote_apply synchronous streaming replication).

What I think is that it is the partially written transactions which are not committed yet and has not yet been replicated to the standby. I have this theory because of the descriptions of the configurations and my failure in finding a case of data loss (losing user's successful transactions after failover).

But I am not sure and I would be glad to have more information about the situation.

Comment: "And this encounters some kind of inconsistency and potentially data loss;" how do you diagnose this?  Is there a specific log message you are referring to?  If so, please quote it, rather than rephrasing it.

Comment: Actually it is determined by the functionality of `pg_rewind`. `pg_rewind` ignores all the local WALs after the point of divergence and follows the new master's WALs in the new timeline. Therefore I think it is obvious that there are some data ignored and deleted when pg_rewind fixes the error mentioned above. But the question is this:
Are the data being ignored committed or not? and following the procedure could it cause data loss?